# Accessing vector with move_iterator

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a std:vector where MyClass can not be copied (copy constructor and assignment constructor are delete), but can be moved

I would like to access the elements in a for loop, how can I do this:

```
for(MyClass c : my_vector) {
    //c should be moved out of my_vector
} // after c goes out of scope, it get's destructed (and no copies exist anymore)
```

I found the [move_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) but I can't figure out how to use it properly in a for loop.

Comment: `for (MyClass& c : my_vector)`, maybe? No copying or moving is needed in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate by reference and move:

```
for (auto & x : v) { foo(std::move(x)); }
```

It may even be more appropriate to use the `std::move`-*algorithm*, from `<algorithm>`, the one that's like `std::copy`. Alternatively maybe something like `std::transform` together with `make_move_iterator()` might suit.

Comment: Is the iterator to the vector still valid after the move?

Comment: @JesseGood: Of course. It's the same as in `Foo x; f(std::move(x));`, where `x` remains a valid object. It's just that the *state* of `x` is unspecified. You're operating on elements, not on the container itself.

Comment: A yes, I hadn't thought of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
for(MyClass &c : my_vector) {
   do_something_with(std::move(c));
}
```

would be what I'd normally do.